# Pass variable from shell script into inline ruby command?

Tags: bash

I want to be able to declare a variable in a shell script and use it in a ruby inline command.  Something like this:

```
foo=kroe761
bar=$(ruby -e 'puts $foo')
echo My name is $bar

$ My name is kroe761.
```

But, what I get is `My name is`. How can I get shell variables into my ruby script?

Comment: Parameter expansion does not happen in the string enclosed in apostrophes. The Ruby code you run is exactly `puts $foo` and, because its name starts with `$`, `$foo` is an uninitialized global variable and the Ruby program does not output anything (it outputs an empty line but the newline is trimmed by `$()`).

Comment: Building the Ruby program in the command line this way is not the right way to do it (and doing it right it's not as easy as it seems). I suggest you to pass `$foo` as an argument to the script in the command line and use the global variable [`ARGV`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) to retrieve it in the program. Something like `ruby -e 'puts ARGV[0]' "$foo"`. It is very important to put `$foo` between quotes, otherwise, if it contains spaces, it is not passed to `ruby` as one argument but the shell splits by spaces into multiple arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not work because the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the command line [does not happen in the strings enclosed in apostrophes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes).

The Ruby code you run is exactly `puts $foo` and, because its name starts with `$`, for the Ruby code `$foo` is an uninitialized global variable. The Ruby program outputs an empty line but [the newline is trimmed by `$()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and the final value stored in the shell variable `bar` is an empty string.

If you try `ruby -e "puts $foo"` (because the parameters are expanded between double quotes) you'll find out that it also does not produce what you want but, even more, it throws an error. The Ruby code it executes is `puts kroe761` and it throws because `kroe761` is an unknown local variable or method name.
Building the Ruby program in the command line this way is not the right way to do it (and doing it right it's not as easy as it seems).

I suggest you to pass the value of `$foo` as an argument to the script in the command line and use the [global variable `ARGV`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) in the Ruby code to retrieve it.

```sh
foo=kroe761
bar=$(ruby -e 'puts ARGV[0]' "$foo")
echo "My name is $bar"
```

It is very important to put `$foo` between quotes, otherwise, if it contains spaces, it is not passed to `ruby` as one argument but the shell [splits it by spaces into multiple arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting).

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0/3za7KD/V3MyQKymxyFZFo6g0qVJBN1VBvaC0pFjBMcg9LNogVl1BSQWoVEmTKzU5I19BybdSIS8xN1Uhs1hBBahN6f9/AA).

Comment: Super helpful!  Thanks!